# Select from 3 tables with calculating

Tags: php, mysql

I try to make a query in MySQL that gets data from 3 tables, and calculate in 2 tables. But i really don't know how to do this.

I have this in my PHP code to calculate "Avage Cost per Click":

1. Get all the campaigns.

   ```
     SELECT * FROM campaigns;
   ```
2. Get how many clicks the campaign has:

   ```
   select SUM(id) as IALT2 from aktivitet where annonce_id = '@@CAMPAIGN_ID' group by ip");
   ```
3. Get the total revenure from all  rows

   ```
   SELECT SUM(price) as IALT from money where ad = '@@CAMPAIGN_ID' group by id
   ```

Now i can calculate the "Avage Cost Per Click"

```
 "IALT / IALT2" = CPC
```

then it should say:

```
select * from campaign order by CPC desc limit 0,1
```

Comment: how are tables related with each other?

Comment: They are 3 different tables. Check the post.

Comment: i know, but how do I know about their relationship column?

Comment: @JW probably with CAMPAIGN_ID like (annonce_id, ad and first one is unknown :/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from campaigns C
order by
(
    (select SUM(price) from money where ad = C.CAMPAIGN_ID)
    /
    (select SUM(id) from aktivitet where annonce_id = C.CAMPAIGN_ID)
)desc limit 0,1
```

just guessing, but I think you want this

Comment: Will this works properly? select * from kampagner C order by
((select SUM(price) from money where short = C.id)/(select COUNT(id) from aktivitet where annonce_id = C.id))
desc